# Integrate the ng2-ace library into a freshly created angular-cli (angular2) project using SystemJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, systemjs

I just created an angular2 project with the latest [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli)  tool. I now want to get the ace editor up and running using the [ng2-ace](https://github.com/seiyria/ng2-ace) library. I want to do it in a clean approach using SystemJS as the module loader.

I did

```
npm install --save ng2-ace
```

then I added the following two lines to `angular-cli-builds.js` to the `vendorNpmFiles` array

```
'ng2-ace/index.js',
'brace/**/*.js
```

then I added the following to `system-config.ts`

```
 const map: any = {
   'ng2-ace': 'vendor/ng2-ace',
   'brace': 'vendor/brace'
 };

 /** User packages configuration. */
 const packages: any = {
   'brace': {
     format: 'cjs',
     defaultExtension: 'js',
     main: 'index.js'
   },
   'ng2-ace': {
     format: 'cjs',
     defaultExtension: 'js',
     main: 'index.js'
   }
 };
```

Now I tried importing the directive from a component

```
import { AceEditorDirective } from 'ng2-ace';
```

This makes the compiler `ng serve` aborting with the following error:

```
The Broccoli Plugin: [BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler] failed with:
Error: Typescript found the following errors:
Cannot find module 'ng2-ace'.
```

I tried to follow the Readme from angular-cli and got the google material design library working. However, I don't know what I do wrong when trying to load the ng2-ace library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason this is so hard is that there's no typings library provided.  I was able to get the rough equivalent of this working by adding a few things.  My version has a pretty static configuration but you can enhance it.

system-config needs this:

```
const map:any = {
  'brace': 'vendor/brace',
  'w3c-blob': 'vendor/w3c-blob',
  'buffer': 'vendor/buffer-shims'
};
```

it may also need:

```
const packages:any = {
  'w3c-blob': {
    format: 'cjs',
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'index.js'
  },

  'brace': {
    format: 'cjs',
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'index.js'
  },

  'buffer': {
    format: 'cjs',
    defaultExtension: 'js',
    main: 'index.js'
  }
};
```

Then you also need to add these things as npm dependencies in angular-cli-build.js:

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      /* your stuff goes here, then add: */
      'brace/**/*.js',
      'w3c-blob/index.js',
      'buffer-shims/index.js'
 ]
});
```

That pretty much gets you everything you need as far as dependencies are concerned.  At this point I added my own directive.  The important parts are here:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

Now import brace itself plus whatever modes and themes you will be using:

```
import 'brace';
declare let ace;

import 'vendor/brace/mode/javascript';
import 'vendor/brace/theme/monokai';
```

The 'declare let ace' lets you have access to brace even though there's no typings and it's not a real typescript module.

I named my directive 'js-editor' and you attach it to a  tag of an appropriate height and width.  The docs for brace say to apply a 'block' style to the div it as well.  Then declare the directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[js-editor]',
  inputs: ['text'],
  outputs: ['textChanged', 'editorRef']
})
export class JsEditor {

  editor : any;
  textChanged : EventEmitter<any>;
  editorRef : EventEmitter<any>;
  value : string;

  set text(value) {
    // if(value === this.oldVal) return;
    // this.editor.setValue(value);
    // this.editor.clearSelection();
    this.editor.focus();
  }

  constructor(elementRef : ElementRef) {
    this.textChanged = new EventEmitter();
    this.editorRef = new EventEmitter();

    const el = elementRef.nativeElement;
    el.classList.add('editor');
```

Setting the base path is the key element to brace being able to find modes and themes. This is really the wrong place to set it - it should be done globally, and ONLY ONCE ... but this was just an experiment to see if it would work so I did it here:

```
    ace.config.set('basePath', 'vendor/brace');
```

Finally, create the editor:

```
    this.editor = ace.edit(el);
```

and then set your mode and theme.  Note that these modes/themes LOOK like paths, but they really are not.  Ace (or perhaps Brace) will use these strings to generate the path using the basePath above:

```
    this.editor.getSession().setMode('ace/mode/javascript');
    this.editor.setTheme('ace/theme/monokai');

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.editorRef.next(this.editor);
    });

    this.editor.on('change', () => {
        /* do whatever you want here */
    });
  }
}
```

That's the general idea.  It really needs to be wrapped up into a nice configurable directive along the lines of ng2-ace but I'm not the right guy to do that, I just wanted to get you headed in the right direction.

--Chris

Comment: If you aren't sure what 'declare let' does, see this  http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2013/07/22/quick-tip-typescript-declare-keyword/